# Changes Text Colors Via Jquery To Asp .Net Web Application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to make changes in text colors which is in  tag  as below.

**Note:-** The below example is of content page hence jquery  is link to master page.

```
<script type="text/jscript">
window.setInterval(function(){
if($("#sw").css("color","Red")){<!—text color in Span Tag-->
$("#sw").css("color","Blue");
 }
else if($("#sw").css("color","Blue")){
$("#sw").css("color","Red");
 }
},1000);

</script>
```

The above example changes my text colors from Red To Blue but it’s not changes from blue to red as per second condition in jquery.
What’s The Problem?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    window.setInterval(function(){
        if ($("#sw").css("color") == "Red") {
            $("#sw").css("color","Blue");
        } else if($("#sw").css("color") == "Blue") {
            $("#sw").css("color","Red");
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Basically you are trying to set the color in the if statement. You should instead check, not set.

Comment: Or you could just use toggle.

Comment: @MelanciaUK true, but you know `toggle()` was removed as per from jquery 1.9 onwards. It was deprecated in jquery 1.8 and removed completely in 1.9.

Comment: @MutieMule, Your Idea is click but friend Remove ")" from If & Else If Block at The end. It's Throw Error Other wise It's Ok

Comment: @MaheshWagh my mistake sorry, have corrected it. Please accept as the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the color now check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tRzAb/

```
setInterval(function(){
if($("#sw").css("color") == "rgb(0, 0, 255)"){
$("#sw").css("color","Red");
 }
else{
$("#sw").css("color","Blue");
 }
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/jscript">
            window.setInterval(
        function () {
            $("#sw").css("color",
                ($("#sw").css("color").trim() == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") ? "rgb(0, 255, 0)" : "rgb(0, 0, 255)"
                );
        }, 500);
        </script>
```